# What is use of tagName, id, and className properties in Backbone View? While we can access dom element with el

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

Why do the properties `tagName`, `id` and `className` exist in a Backbone View?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Those properties are used if your view has to create its own element, that is, if it doesn't have a `el` attribute when instantiated (various reasons, I can go further in the matter). So you'll have a new element with the id `id`, classes `className` and attributes `attributes`.

You can find the [relevant piece of code here](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/d52ed125a853519b74786fa3d6a3518c8c634d21/backbone.js#L1185). This `_ensureElement` method is used in the view's constructor.

Comment: how do we render the custom element into the desired location in the DOM?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Just like you would add any other html into the DOM. Something like `$("#container").html(myView.$el);`

Answer (score 22):

All Backbone views have an el property [Read doc here](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el).
If you do not pass an el while instantiating a view, it will create an empty `DIV` and use it.

- Now, just say you do not want to use `DIV` as the container to render your view. You want it to be a `UL` instead. Just specify the `tagName` property for your view and it will be used instead.
- If you want to add some css classes to your container, use `className`.
- If you want to add some attributes to it (For example you want to add `data-*` attributes to your el) use the `attributes` property of Backbone view.

Comment: As per the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el), ```attributes ``` is used to create ```this.el```: "this.el is created from the view's tagName, className, id and attributes properties, if specified". So you can also set ```attributes.class```. It is NOT specifically for ```data-*``` attributes, although it can be used for that, as well as anything settable via ```jQuery.attr()```

Comment: how do we render the custom element into the desired location in the DOM?